# result of sys_get_temp_dir() not writable by Apache process's user

Tags: php, apache, unix, permissions, assetic

I've been working with Assetic and YUICompressor to minify and concat js/css.

I'm having a problem figuring out the correct write permission working on my local testing environment and the result of PHP's `sys_get_temp_dir()` which Assetic relies on.

I use MAMP to manage my testing environment and per the MAMP team's suggestion I run Apache as user '_www' which is a problem since the folders that `sys_get_temp_dir()` return have permissions set to my local user.

For instance, `sys_get_temp_dir()` will return something like

`/private/var/folders/41/t37ngfqd1m7dczjdr91s5vb40000gn/T`

which has the permissions

`drwx------   8 myname  staff   272B May  4 13:23 T`

So far the only thing I've been able to accomplish is to do the `chmod 777`, which guarantees personal misfortune and a tongue lashing from the RTM crowd. I get it, it's to permissive, but I haven't been able to make the leap to figure out the right permissions to allow `_www` to write to a folder returned by `sys_get_temp_dir()` in a predictable safe way.

I've tried (what I can only guess are still bad but slightly less than 777):

- going to the Finder (yep, OSX) right-click-get-info the `/private/var/folders/` directory and granting `_www` read/write permissions recursively — doesn't work
- tried adding `_www` to the 'wheel' and 'staff' groups. Doesn't work because (as evidenced above) the folder returned is *only* writable by user `myname` (even though `/private/var/folders` is owned by the `wheel` group and certain folders are owned by `staff` group)

So, if I can't add `_www` to a group, and I can't ACL the folder recursively, do I have to just run MAMP as user `myname`? There's got to be some Unix-fu I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Your folder has only permissions for the owner, in other words drwx------ means the same as 700. The group the folder belongs to is staff, so you may either add _www to the group staff, or change the group of the folder to _www. Furthermore, you need to set group permissions too, so if you want read and write and execute permissions to the group, you may set the permissions to 770. The second number of the permission code is group permissions.

Comment: Yes, that does work. At some point though the temp-directory could churn and return a new folder with the permissions `drwx------` — curious if there is a way to set permissions to futurer directories under `/private/var/foldrs/…`? I thought something like this was possible with ACL but I haven't been able to reason it out.

Comment: i found some info about that here http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1011132 which points here http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071207091554360

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Re: 1st link, I know I don't want to `chown` the folder to `_www`. Re: 2nd link, I'll try `unmask` and see what happens